# How to design a template to access the first element with either std::queue.front() or std::priority_queue.top()?

Tags: c++, templates

When I design a template

```
template<typename T, 
typename QueueType,
typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<QueueType, std::queue<T>> || std::is_same_v<QueueType, std::priority_queue<T>>>
class ThreadSafeQueue {
private:
QueueType q;
public:
T& get();
};
```

As shown, `QueueType` is either std::queue or std::priority_queue;But if I want to access the first element with `T& get()`, the basic function of `std::queue` is `front()` whereas `std::priority_queue` is `top()`.So how to design `T& get()` to access the first element?

Answer (score 3):

In C++20, you can do the following using the new [requires clause](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>

template<
    typename T, 
    typename QueueType,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<QueueType, std::queue<T>> || std::is_same_v<QueueType, std::priority_queue<T>>
    >
>
class ThreadSafeQueue {
    private:
        QueueType q;
    public:
        T& get() requires (std::is_same_v<QueueType, std::queue<T>>) {
            return q.front();
        }
        const T& get() requires (std::is_same_v<QueueType, std::priority_queue<T>>) {
            return q.top();
        }
};

int main() {
    ThreadSafeQueue<int, std::queue<int>> a;
    ThreadSafeQueue<int, std::priority_queue<int>> b;
    a.get();
    b.get();
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Wa6x8Kdo9

---

You can also use `if constexpr` from C++17.

```cpp
decltype(auto) get() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<QueueType, std::queue<T>>) {
        return q.front();
    }
    else {
        return q.top();
    }
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7vPoWrf1x

Comment: Hum, why not use `if constexpr`?

Comment: @康桓瑋: Fair point. I initially wanted to leave the door open for `const &T` and `&T` return types, but ended up not showing that. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

You can delegate to overloads.

Assuming that you want both instantiations to have the same interface, `get()` must return a const reference as that is what you get from `priority_queue::top`.

Sketch:

```
const T& internal_get(std::queue<T>& q) { return q.front(); }

const T& internal_get(std::priority_queue<T>& q) { return q.top(); }

const T& get() { return internal_get(q); }
```

If you want the `queue` instantiation to have a mutable `get()`, you need something like

```
T& internal_get(std::queue<T>& q) { return q.front(); }

const T& internal_get(std::priority_queue<T>& q) { return q.top(); }        

decltype(auto) get() { return internal_get(q); }
```

but I think that could get pretty confusing.

Comment: Mind that `priority_queue` has only `const_reference top() const;` overload, which cannot be bound to `T&`

Comment: @pptaszni Of course.

Answer (score 2):

One *can* provide specialisations, one *can* provide overloads (the latter I'd consider superior over the former) – but one can, too, look if the template argument classes do provide the appropriate functions!

A pretty simple variant for such a test might look as follows:

```
template <typename T>
auto has_front(T t) -> decltype(t.front());
void has_front(...);

template <typename T>
bool constexpr has_front_v
    = !std::is_void_v<decltype(has_front(std::declval<T>()))>;

template <typename T>
auto has_top(T t) -> decltype(t.top());
void has_top(...);

template <typename T>
bool constexpr has_top_v = !std::is_void_v<decltype(has_top(std::declval<T>()))>;
```

As is, these tests would fail for classes providing the respective function but with void return value. In given case this is irrelevant as such function wouldn't serve the purpose anyway. For the general case a variant a bit more precise (in sense of testing mere existence) could look as follows:

```
template <typename T>
auto has_function(T t) -> decltype(t.function(), std::true_type());
std::false_type has_function(...);

template <typename T>
bool constexpr has_function_v = decltype(has_function(std::declval<T>()))::value;
```

With such tests provided you now can use `if constexpr` to test which function to use for value retrieval:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) get(T& t)
{
    if constexpr(has_front_v<T>)
    {
        return t.front();
    }
    else
    {
        static_assert(has_top_v<T>);
        return t.top();
    }
}
```

Bonus of this variant: It works, too, with *any* container providing one of the two functions in question like e.g. `std::vector` or `std::string` (in above implementation `front` would be preferred over `top` if a container provided both).

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ebxeT31nY).